# Check checkbox if any of the checkboxes is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

HTML

```
<label for="desktop_dimension_id">Desktop dimensions:</label>
    <span class="checkbox" id="desktopCheckboxId">
    <span class="checkbox_value">
<input id="dc1280_800" type="checkbox" name="1280x800"> 1280x800</span>                    
<span class="checkbox_value">
<input id="dc1366_768" type="checkbox" name="1366x768"> 1366x768</span>
<span class="checkbox_value">
<input id="dc1920_1080" type="checkbox" name="1920x1080"> 1920x1080</span>
</span>

    <br/>                    
 <input id="desktopCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1"> Desktop
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
if(jQuery('#desktopCheckboxId input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        document.getElementById('desktopCheckbox').checked = this.checked;
    }
```

I want to check the desktop checkbox is any of the first three checkboxes is checked. Have been trying several methods but doesn't seem to work for unknown reasons. So how will I be able to do that?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmZ7T/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pmZ7T/3/)</kbd>

```
var chk = $('.checkbox_value input[type=checkbox]');
chk.change(function () {
    $('#desktopCheckbox').prop('checked', chk.filter(':checked').length > 0);
});
```

---

References

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: @vephelp Place your code in DOM ready as in fiddle -->http://jsfiddle.net/pmZ7T/6/

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/pmZ7T/

Try this one.

```
$("#frmTest input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#desktopCheckbox").attr("checked","checked");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do like below:

```
$('#desktopCheckbox').prop('checked', $('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0);
```

But you may mean to bind with change event.

```
$('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $('#desktopCheckbox').prop('checked', $('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0);
}).change();
```

***[See the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/pmZ7T/2/)***

Comment: working fine here, but doesn't work in my code. I'm using `jquery-1.8.0.min.js`, can that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

how about this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/GGEFp/ **<== will return false*

http://jsfiddle.net/D23eA/ **<== will return true**

API: `length` http://api.jquery.com/length/

Rest should fit the need `:)`

**Code**

```
var atLeastOne = $('#desktopCheckboxId :checkbox:checked').length > 0;
```

Comment: @vephelp check the demo which return false `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/GGEFp/ , you probably will be missing `document.ready` also please make sure its with `.change` event as well like the demo above my post. by xdazzz `:)`

Answer (score 1):

you can just set checked = true...

```
if (jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        document.getElementById('desktopCheckbox').checked = true;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmZ7T/4/

(btw, your fiddle was also looking for a form id that didn't exist... "frmTest")